# Adding data to a model in Django

Tags: python, django

I have a Django model called "Post" that is supposed to be similar to a Facebook post. This model has a field called "body". I also have a template with a textarea and a button.

The functionality I am trying to implement is when I click the button in the template, I want to extract the text from the textarea and instantiate and save a new Post object and add it to the existing view.

Essentially, I am trying to implement the same functionality in the /admin directory that allows you to create new objects in a model.

I'm new to Django, and want to make sure I am using best practices from the get-go. What is the flow of a process like this in Django? Thanks.

**Edit:**

I want to implement the same exact functionality as Facebook's where there is a textarea for your status, and when you press submit, it is immediately added to your stream. What is the "correct" way to implement this in Django?

Comment: Have you tried the django docs. https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/intro/tutorial04/

Comment: Try this [link](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/forms/#building-a-form-in-django) which gives a small tutorial on submitting forms

Comment: @brainlesscoder I read that doc, but it seems fairly complex for what I want. I guess my intuition told me there would be a simple way to call the model constructor in the template or in javascript. However, if that's the only way, I guess I'll just have to use that.

Comment: @JasonEstibeiro that link helps a lot, thanks.

Comment: @rigdonmr - You can also go through this [link](http://www.djangobook.com/en/2.0/chapter07.html) to get a better understanding.

Answer (score 0):

So what you want is basically for the data to appear after the request without being redirected away from the current template?

Comment: "...without being redirected away from the current template?" That's not really the part I care about. I guess what I'm really asking is how do I create a new Post object, and then perhaps re-render the same template, which will then include the newly added post. See what I mean?

Answer (score 0):

On your view file you have to save the post data and then return a render to response with all your posts objects.
On your django template you should loop through all your posts objects and then show a form( method ='post' action='yourviewurl' ) where you can post new data.when you submit the form this will redirect you to the same page and loads all the posts objects
Facebook is using a lot of javascript. 
So if you want to make it without page refreshing , you should learn some javascript and django rest framework
If you post some code , maybe i can help you more

Answer (score 0):

All you need to do is to create a form and add it to any template you want. Then you need to add Ajax functionality to the form so you will be able to submit a form without reloading the page. After the ajax call has been completed and your object has been created you update your template using javascript. That's all.

As you haven't included any code it's impossible to help you with the code, so I would definitly reccomend you to google for "Django forms + ajax" or something like this to see some examples.